# Set Primary Billing Address and Primary Shipping Address

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3

We have a site using Craft 3.6.11 and Commerce 3.3.5.1

We give users the options to create and account enter an address.  Is there anyway to also have this address set as the Primary Billing Address and Primary Shipping Address when they do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same requirement a while ago. Not 100% sure if this is still necessary, but at the time I needed to do it via custom code in a module. It looks like this:

```php
use Craft;
use craft\services\Elements;
use craft\commerce\models\Address as AddressModel;
use craft\commerce\records\Customer as CustomerRecord;
use craft\commerce\records\CustomerAddress as CustomerAddressRecord;
use craft\commerce\Plugin as CommercePlugin;

// --------------------------------------------
// SAVE COMMERCE CUSTOMER ADDRESS AFTER REGISTRATION
// --------------------------------------------

Event::on(
    Elements::class,
    Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    function(Event $e) {
        // Bail out on console requests
        if (Craft::$app->request->isConsoleRequest) { return; }

        // Bail out if it's not a User element being saved
        if (!$e->element instanceof \craft\elements\User) { return; }

        // Bail out on CP requests
        if (Craft::$app->request->isCpRequest) { return; }

        // get the address fields from the POST data...
        $add1 = Craft::$app->request->getBodyParam('address');

        $userId = $e->element->id;
        $address = new AddressModel();

        $address->attention = '';
        $address->title = '';
        $address->firstName = '';
        $address->lastName = '';
        $address->fullName = '';
        $address->address1 = $add1['address1'];
        $address->address2 = $add1['address2'];
        $address->address3 = '';
        $address->city = $add1['city'];
        $address->zipCode = $add1['zipCode'];
        $address->phone = '';
        $address->alternativePhone = '';
        $address->label = '';
        $address->notes = '';
        $address->businessName = '';
        $address->businessTaxId = '';
        $address->businessId = '';
        $address->countryId = 77;
        $address->stateName = $add1['stateValue'];
        $address->custom1 = '';
        $address->custom2 = '';
        $address->custom3 = '';
        $address->custom4 = '';
        $address->id = 0;

        // Save it
        $addressSaved = CommercePlugin::getInstance()->getAddresses()->saveAddress($address);

        // now tie it to a new record in craft_commerce_customers_addresses
        if ($addressSaved) {
            $customer = (new \craft\commerce\services\Customers)->getCustomerByUserId($userId);

            $customerAddressRecord = new CustomerAddressRecord();
            $customerAddressRecord->customerId = $customer->id;
            $customerAddressRecord->addressId = $address->id;
            $customerAddressSaved = $customerAddressRecord->save();

            $customerRecord = CustomerRecord::findOne($customer->id);
            $customerRecord->primaryShippingAddressId = $address->id;
            $customerRecord->save();
        }        
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks James, I've also found a way to do it as below

Answer (score 1):

As well as James answer above, the following should do it:

```
{% set isPrimaryBilling = cart.customer.primaryBillingAddressId == addressId %}
{% set isPrimaryShipping = cart.customer.primaryShippingAddressId == addressId %}

<label for="makePrimaryShippingAddress">
    <input id="makePrimaryShippingAddress"name="makePrimaryShippingAddress" type="checkbox" {{ isPrimaryShipping ? 'checked' :'' }}/>
    <span>Make this the primary shipping address</span>
</label>
<label for="makePrimaryBillingAddress">
    <input id="makePrimaryBillingAddress" name="makePrimaryBillingAddress" type="checkbox" {{ isPrimaryBilling ? 'checked' :'' }}/>
    <span>Make this the primary billing address</span>
</label>
```

Comment: But doesn't that only work from a commerce form action, such as `commerce/cart/update-cart`? Didn't you want it to happen from the user registration form?

Comment: HI James, I tested this and can confirm this works to set the options.  You also have to set the cart object using something like: {% if cart is not defined %}
  {% set cart = craft.commerce.carts.cart %}
{% endif %}

Comment: Are you saying this works from a submission of the user registration form?? That would be surprising.

Comment: Hi James, that's right, I've tested it and it does work.  You have to set the cart object as above, but this does work.